# Data access in multi-threaded app

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm using the following code to run several threads to process some time-consuming tasks :

```
  public void RunWhileRemainThreads()
    {
        string[] options = new string[2];
        int i = 0;

        while (LeftToRun > 0)
        {
            if (CurrentRunningThreads < MaxThreadsRunning)
            {
                options[0] = list_test[i];
                options[1] = bla;

                BackgroundWorker myThread = new BackgroundWorker();
                myThread.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorkerRemoteProcess_DoWork);
                myThread.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorkerRemoteProcess_RunWorkerCompleted);
                myThread.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorkerRemoteProcess_ProgressChanged);
                myThread.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                myThread.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

                myThread.RunWorkerAsync(options);

                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                CurrentRunningThreads++;
                i++;
                LeftToRun--;
            }
        }
    }

        private void backgroundWorkerRemoteProcess_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] options = (string[])e.Argument;
            string option1 = options[0];
            string option2 = options[1];

            RemoteProcess myRemoteProcess = new RemoteProcess(option1, option2);
            myRemoteProcess.FalseExec();
        }
```

My problem is that when I run this without the `Thread.Sleep(3000)`, the `option1` variable is the same! (I print it from within `RemoteProcess.FalseExec()`).

I guess I should manage this parameter differently but I cannot find how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to stop sharing the same array between all background workers:

```
public void RunWhileRemainThreads()
{
    int i = 0;

    while (LeftToRun > 0)
    {
        if (CurrentRunningThreads < MaxThreadsRunning)
        {
            options[0] = ;
            options[1] = bla;

            BackgroundWorker myThread = new BackgroundWorker();
            myThread.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorkerRemoteProcess_DoWork);
            myThread.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorkerRemoteProcess_RunWorkerCompleted);
            myThread.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorkerRemoteProcess_ProgressChanged);
            myThread.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            myThread.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

            // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT CHANGE
            myThread.RunWorkerAsync(new string[2] { list_test[i], bla });

            CurrentRunningThreads++;
            i++;
            LeftToRun--;
        }
    }
}
```

This way each `BackgroundWorker` will receive a different `string[]` as its parameter, so there's no chance that two workers will get the same value.

Comment: Works great ! I didn't know I can run : myThread.RunWorkerAsync(new string[2] { list_test[i], bla });